# jQuery / JavaScript on page unload from div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is what i want to accomplish, and i will try to simplify things.

This are my buttons used for navigation:

```
<button id="one">One</button>
<button id="two">Two</button>
<button id="three">Three</button>
```

In body i have a div called "placeholder":

```
<div id="placeholder"></div>
```

Load content from some other pages into that div when button is clicked:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#one').click(function(){
        $('#placeholder').load("pageone.php");
    });
    $('#two').click(function(){
        $('#placeholder').load("pagetwo.php");
    });
    $('#three').click(function(){
        $('#placeholder').load("pagethree.php");
    });
});
```

Let's say user clicked on button "one" and currently content from "pageone.php" is loaded into "placeholder", and now he clicks on some other button. I want to execute some code once "pageone.php" is not loaded (visible on the screen) anymore, regardless of which page is loaded now into that div.

So not sure if i explained good but I don't want to execute code when some other button is clicked or other page is loaded.

I want to execute code once "pageone.php" is not loaded anymore.

I've used jQuery here but pure JS answer could use as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can't just ask to solve for your issue, show us what did you tried so far? Here take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read post on [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var old_page = "";
    var new_page = "";

    $('#one').click(function(){
        $('#placeholder').load("pageone.php");
        new_page = "one";
        check();
    });
    $('#two').click(function(){
        $('#placeholder').load("pagetwo.php");
        new_page = "two";
        check();
    });
    $('#three').click(function(){
        $('#placeholder').load("pagethree.php");
        new_page = "three";
        check();
    });
    function check() {
        if(new_page!==old_page) {
            // old page is unloaded.
            // do your code here
            // once done, don't forget to update old_page
            old_page = new_page;
        } else {
            // same page is loaded again
            // you may want to do something different here

        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a callback to the load function like this.

```
$('#two').click(function(){
    $( "#placeholder" ).load( "pagetwo.php", function() {
       alert( "Pageone is not loaded." );
    });
});
```